# Is it possible to use Raspberry Pi as keyboard/mouse/joystick to control a Windows PC?

Tags: windows, networking, raspberry-pi

I have a unused laptop (Win7 64bit) with broken USB port, so I cannot plug any USB device in it. But the laptop itself is good enough to play indie games or any games from last gen.

Is it possible to plug in mouse/keyboard/joystick to my raspberry Pi and use it to control the laptop?

Comment: There is a program called [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/) which may work for you. It said it is compatible with Linux.. so there may be hope. The idea is that you use a single keyboard / mouse and it can "travel" between one screen to another. The problem I can think of is that you move your keyboard and mouse focus to your laptop... but if you ever move your mouse (by accident) out of your laptop monitor, it will be "gone" for a while into the other screen (the pi screen or other devices) until you move it back to the laptop screen. Not sure if it supports joystick.

Comment: Bluetooth is also a possibility. Either getting bluetooth peripherals or getting a bluetooth usb hub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using a program called VirtualHere, it's a software to allow USB devices to be used over network. You can install it on your Raspberry Pi, just plug your USB devices on the Pi and your Windows machine can start using the device as if they were directly attached.